# Find the minimum value of $t^3+t^2-2t-2$ given that $t$ is greater than or equal to 2

Tags: real-analysis, functions

The original question was to find the range of the function f defined by:
$$f(x)=\frac {(1+x+x^2)(1+x^4)}{x^3}$$ for $x>0$

Evidently, differentiating is not very helpful. So I wrote $f(x)$ as:
$$f(x)=t^3+t^2-2t-2=(t^2-2)(t+1)$$
Where $t=x+\frac 1x$

The maximum value clearly approaches $+\infty$.

How do I find the minimum value, where $t >=2$? Here, too differentiating would not help, unless I want to plot a graph, which would again be somewhat cumbersome.

Comment: Why do you think differentiating would not help?

Comment: @DanielFischer it would help (it always helps somewhat) , but not if this question turns up in an examination, and you've got to do it in a minute or so.

Comment: It would surely help if you decided to go for it, given that you went that far. However, from your analysis, you could just say that $g(t)$ is increasing as are both $t^2-2$ and $t+1$.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean $g(t)$ is minimum when $t^2-2$ or $t+1$ is minimum, whichever gives a lower value.

Comment: It is all over once you make the substitution: $t=2$. Note by the way that you should have divided the first term by $x$ and the second by $x^2$, which gives the factorization automatically.

Comment: By the way, congratulations on the substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is *your solution*, and is very nice.  Note that our function is equal to 
$$\frac{1+x+x^2}{x}\cdot \frac{1+x^4}{x^2},$$
which is 
$$\left(x+1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right).$$
Make the substitution $x+\frac{1}{x}=t$. Our function is equal to 
$$(t+1)(t^2-2).\tag{1}$$
Since $t\ge 2$, the function (1) is increasing, so has a minimum value of $6$ at $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

I woud say that

$\left(\frac{(1+x+x^2)(1+x^4)}{x^3}\right)' = \frac{3 x^6+2 x^5+x^4-x^2-2 x-3}{x^4}$

The equation $3 x^6+2 x^5+x^4-x^2-2 x-3=0$ is a negatively reciprocal equation of odd degree, obviously has roots

$x=1, x=-1 \Rightarrow 3 x^6+2 x^5+x^4-x^2-2 x-3 = (x-1)(x+1)(3 x^4+2 x^3+4 x^2+2 x+3) = 0$

The equation $3 x^4+2 x^3+4 x^2+2 x+3=0$ is a positively reciprocal equation, solution

after adjusting the shape dividing $x^2$, substitution $t = x + \frac{1}{x} \Rightarrow$ quadratic equation, this has no real roots.

So may be extreme at points x = -1 or x = 1.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding $f(x)$ and breaking the fraction,
$$f(x)=\frac{(1+x+x^2)(1+x^4)}{x^3}=\frac{1+x+x^2+x^4+x^5+x^6}{x^3}=\frac 1{x^3}+\frac 1{x^2}+\frac 1x+x+x^2+x^3.$$

Can you differentiate $f(x)$ now? Only the power rule is required for the last expression.

Comment: I could, if I tried, differentiate the original expression, if it simplified the analysis. In both cases, the expression in the answer, and the function g(t) I found it difficult to draw conclusions from the derivative, except that the functions were increasing, for $x>0$.